# laravel 4 queue(SQS and Elasticbeanstalk) failed to open stream:Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

My queue task is like below

```
$message = "message";
Queue::push(function($job) use ($message)
{
    echo "user of queue runnur : ".get_current_user();
    Log::info($data,$message.get_current_user());
    $job->delete();
});
```

However,I got

```
user of queue runnur : webapp
The stream or file "/var/app/current/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The logs directory is changed to 775 by myself.And I have test the writing in non-queue method and it can write successfully.

The file permission

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 webapp webapp 1269117 Jun 24 07:59 laravel.log
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two situation will cause laravel 4 queue failed to open stream exception,

1.Permission problem,queue runner don't have the file/directory permission to read or write.Plz change the file permission is 775.

2.Wrong path.The  current directory of script that is running is absolutely different between the website entry point(index.php) and queue runner.

In order to debug,please push this job and run to view related information

```
    Queue::push(function($job) use ($message)
   {
        echo "user = ".get_current_user();
        echo "current directory = " . getcwd();
        $job->delete();
    });
```

In my case ,it was caused by situation 2,the current directory of website is /rootOfProject/public and the queue runner is /rootOfProject

Answer (score 3):

Your queue runner is running on a different user than the website or the webserver. The laravel.log file is created by the web server or the php process. The queue handler is running as a different user and attempts to write into the log file as seen from your `Log::info()` call. However this user has no access to the file created by a different user.

How is your queue runner configured?

Comment: I rewrite the code and test again to rule out the possibility that the queue runner is not in the group of the script owner.(Updated in topic).Is it a place to configure queue runner?Because in laravel 4,only a queue.php is available for configuration of queue.Thank you for you helps.